# SQL Server BULK INSERT mess up varbinary

Tags: sql-server

I have an input file with records

```
1,2014030000000212,0x060000000000000000000000000000
1,2014030000000215,0x050000000000000000000000000000
1,2014030000000221,0x080000000000000000000000000000
```

I use a `FormatFile`

```
11.0
3
1       SQLINT              0       4       ","        1     ClientCode               ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       20      ","        2     AccountID                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLBINARY           0       64      "\r\n"     3     mask                     ""
```

when I use `BULK INSERT TempBinaryMask from 'C:\Temp\BinaryData.txt' WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\BinaryFormat.txt')` it inserts the data, but it messes up my varbinaries, and it looks like this

```
49          2014030000000212     0x3078303630303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030
49          2014030000000215     0x3078303530303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030
49          2014030000000221     0x3078303830303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030
```

I also just noticed that my ClientCode is also wrong. it is 49 instead of 1. If there something I'm doing wrong?

This is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE TempBinaryMask 
(
    ClientCode int,
    AccountID varchar(20),
    mask varbinary(64)
)
```

Comment: [This article](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/how-to-import-a-varbinarymax-column-with-bulk-import) may be helpful to you.

Comment: For some reason a `formatfile` is the problem, if I use `BULK INSERT TempBinaryMask from 'C:\Temp\BinaryData.txt' WITH (DATAFILETYPE='char', FIELDTERMINATOR=',')` and take the `0x` away in front of the Binary data, it imports perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Please answer your own question, as this may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason a `FormatFile` is the problem.

I changed my input file to

```
1,2014030000000212,060000000000000000000000000000
1,2014030000000215,050000000000000000000000000000
1,2014030000000221,080000000000000000000000000000
```

and used

```
BULK INSERT TempBinaryMask from 'C:\Temp\BinaryData.txt' WITH (DATAFILETYPE='char', FIELDTERMINATOR=',')
```

to import the data, and it worked perfectly.

I've tried the XML format file, as well as the non-XML, and both gave me different types of errors